# R save outcome in a word document on a mac

Tags: r, macos, ms-word, save

How do I save outcome in the console (e.g. a table) as a word document on a Mac?
I tried the R2wd package, but that only works for windows. Is there an alternative?

Comment: how about `odfWeave` package? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`R2HTML`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2HTML/index.html) to save as an HTML document.  Word can open these, so you can then resave in DOC format if you want.

---

For tables, you can save to CSV, open in Excel, then copy and paste into Word, which automatically creates a table.

Slightly fancier is to use [`xlsx`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/index.html) to save as an XLS spreadsheet, then do Insert -> Object... -> Microsoft Excel Worksheet.  This can drastically increase the file size though.